# angular - bind element to existing component

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, angular9

i have `ParentComponent` continans `public Child:ChildComponent` componentns

`ParentComponent` template contains `<child [ngModel]="child"></child>`

i got this error 
'**No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute**'

what is the correct way to bind two existsing components

Comment: ngModel property is allowed on components that implements ControlValueAccessor
https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor

Comment: if you only want to have two way binding, but without using ngModel, it can be done without implementing controlValueAccessor. specify your case. whether its mandatory to use keyword ngModel, or other kind of twoway binding will do?

Comment: the case is tree, but all node are generated in background byself, html are display the state without generating components

Comment: use input and output for communication between two component